# OpenIdDict: reason of failed authentication in HttpContext?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, oauth, openiddict

I have a RESTful application that `using OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore` and Bearer tokens. The ASP.NET Controller evaluates the token (if present), but does not *require* authentication (thus, it is possible to request "public" data even without a token); `[Authorize]` attribute is not set.

Only when token authentication succeeds, more confidential data is returned. The authentication information is pulled from `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`, combined with the fact whether the token is in the header  or not.

### Question:

Does OpenIdDict somehow store the *reason* why authentication has failed (thus, `IsAuthenticated` stays `false`) in the `HttpContext` object, like:

- no bearer token
- invalid signature
- valid signature, but expired

etc., to allow more detailed reaction?

Edit: I changed my approach a bit and return a proper http 401 status in case the token is invalid. Still I am interested whether the reason can be extracted.

Answer (score 0):

The error details can be retrieved by accessing the `AuthenticationProperties` attached to the failed `AuthenticateResult`:

```cs
var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
var error = result.Properties.Items[OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.Error];
var description = result.Properties.Items[OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ErrorDescription];
```